# How to insert multiple rows in a single query using a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_insertgender
    (@gendervalues VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sparsha.dbo.Genders ([GenderName])
    VALUES @gendervalues;
END
```

I tried above procedure but I am getting an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Usp_insertgender, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near '@gendervalues'.

I am passing `@gendervalues` values as ('1'),('2')

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way is to define [TVP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine):

```
CREATE TYPE myTVPType AS TABLE( v VARCHAR(50));  
GO  

CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_insertgender (@gendervalues myTVPType READONLY) 
AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO sparsha.dbo.Genders ([GenderName]) 
  SELECT v
  FROM @gendervalues; 
END;
```

---

How to call it:

```
DECLARE @tvp AS myTVPType;  

INSERT INTO @TVP (v)  
VALUES ('1'),('2');

EXEC Usp_insertgender @TVP;  
GO
```

Comment: When am executing procedure  getting error                                                    
   execute Usp_insertgender (1),(2)    Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: hi lad2025 thanks for giving solution to how to call Procedure.                   
 plz give a solution to how to  call it on stored procedure by giving parameter as ('1'),('2') and insert multiple values. here the problem is above inserting depends on another insert query.

Comment: `by giving parameter as ('1'),('2')` The only way I see is dynamic SQL but it will be huge antipattern to present it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (with dynamic SQL)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_insertgender
    (@gendervalues VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)

    SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO sparsha.dbo.Genders ([GenderName])
    VALUES ' + @gendervalues

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: @guna: Hi, you've received two good answers. Please accept one of them